# Central Admin opens blank post wsp deploment

Tags: 2016, central-administration, web-application, solution-deployment

I have deployed a solution on my farm at global level, after that I retracted it to deploy some changes. But as soon as I retracted the solution the Central Admin and the web apps started opening blank. I was not able to open anything on Central Admin, neither on web app and could not find anything on logs.
 I did some research and found a workaround in which I changed the **Web.config** for Central Admin and the other web apps and post that it started opening.
 The changes made were below :

> `customErrors mode="Off"` Previously it was **On** 
>  
>   `compilation batch="false" debug="true"` Previously value for debug was **false**

But this is just a workaround and this has to be done for every new web app I am creating now.

Can someone guide me to find out what could be the root cause of this problem and how to resolve it permanently.

Comment: perhaps you could reprovision CA via wizard as described in https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3353ad18-4390-4576-90bd-7b91e4e1f577/central-administration-blank-page-after-successful-installation?forum=sharepointadmin

Comment: @Celophysis No, It did not  help.